# How to iterate through a Parameters tuples in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do you iterate though the TestParams tuple? I know that you can access it by index. But I want to go through each parameter type using iteration. Like a for

```
function auxFunction(arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: boolean): string {
       return arg1 + arg2;
}

type TestParams = Parameters<typeof auxFunction>;
```

Notice that if I use the following line it shows an error: **'i' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof i'?**

```
let i = 0;
type ParamType = TestParams[i];
```

Comment: Do you mean iterate through the parameters at runtime or map the parameter types into another type? You cannot access types at runtime.

Comment: In addition to Sno2's comment, this sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/252139). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the new parameter and create variables based on those parameters. For example:

let newParam : ParamType 

Then use it and move on with the next parameter

Comment: How do you "use it"? It's easy to imagine doing something with it in the emitted JS, but having a TypeScript type for it and doing something productive with it sounds a bit odd to me

Comment: Types do not exist at runtime, so you cannot iterate over them with executable code. Also, you cannot dynamically create variables, they must be explicitly declared like `const myVarName`. Please give a better example that shows what you are really after. I don't see iteration in your example, just fetching one index. Even if the example doesn't compile, make it demonstrate your goal.